# Less productivity with shared responsibility

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there a phrase for the idea that there is seemingly less productivity when responsibility for something is shared?

For example when there is only one person to do the housework, it will get done because only they can do it. If it is shared between multiple people it may take longer as each individual expects the other to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The bystander effect

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect)

Although its primary example is a bit more advanced than what you're asking about, the underlying principle is the same:

> The bystander effect, or bystander apathy, is a social psychological phenomenon in which **individuals are less likely to offer help to a victim when other people are present**. The greater the number of bystanders, the less likely it is that any one of them will help. Several factors contribute to the bystander effect, including ambiguity, cohesiveness and **diffusion of responsibility**.

The general idea is that when a group of participants increases, that everyone is more likely to think "oh, there's bound to be someone, more qualified than me, who should be handling this".

Comment: That fits what I was trying to describe perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No phrase that I know of except "Many hands make light work."   But it's only common sense that if NO ONE accepts responsibility, then no one cares.   But it only one person is responsible, then that particular person has his/her reputation at stake and probably wants to be thought of as reliable or they wouldn't have accepted the assignment.   Ergo, if that person has any self-respect, then that same person will see to it that the work gets done.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for but thank you for the phrase and explanation